# Identifying the run lengths of a MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas

Given a pandas MultiIndex like this:

```
pd.Index([['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C'],
          ['W', 'W', 'X', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']])
```

what's an efficient way of identifying the run length of each level? The result I'm expecting is:

```
('Level 1',     # Under level 1
    ('A', 3),   #   A is repeated thrice
    ('B', 2),   #   followed by B, twice
    ('C', 1),), #   and then by C, once
('Level 2',     # Under level 2
    ('W', 2),   #   W is repeated twice
    ('X', 1),   #   X is split between A (once)
    ('X', 1),   #   ... and B (once)
    ('Y', 1),   #   followed by Y, once
    ('Z', 1),   #   and then by Z, once
)
```

Incidentally, this is identical to how Pandas formats a MultiIndex when
rendering as HTML. However, the source (`core/format.py` -
`HTMLFormatter._write_header`) involves looping and appears less efficient
than I'd like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another way, this might be the simplest approach and generalizes easily to more dimensions:

```
idx = pd.Index([['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C'],
                ['W', 'W', 'X', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']])

df = pd.DataFrame( np.ones(len(idx[0])), index=[idx[0],idx[1]] )

df.groupby(level=[0]).count()

   0
A  3
B  2
C  1

df.groupby(level=[0,1]).count()

     0
A W  2
  X  1
B X  1
  Y  1
C Z  1
```

Comment: Thanks @JohnE. I agree: this might be the simplest and most general.

Answer (score 1):

(**edited** to deal with uniqueness aspect)

Same rough idea as @Primer, I'm just leaving it a little simpler.  This should be about as efficient as you could to it for the first level, I'd think:

```
pd.Series(idx[0]).value_counts()

A    3
B    2
C    1
```

The output is also a Series, so you have lots of options for displaying or converting to a dictionary, etc.

The second level is a little tougher (because the counts need to measure uniqueness in combination with the first level).  The index here is a little ugly but does demonstrate how the two levels go together:

```
ser = pd.Series( [ i+j for i,j in zip( idx[0], idx[1] ) ] ).value_counts()

AW    2
CZ    1
BY    1
BX    1
AX    1
```

You may prefer to display more like this:

```
pd.Series( ser.values, index=ser.reset_index()['index'].str[1:] )

index
W    2
Z    1
Y    1
X    1
X    1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using Counter.  It is very efficient.

The first line of code uses list comprehension to create a list of each level together with the unique elements and their counts:
[[('A', 3), ('C', 1), ('B', 2)], [('Y', 1), ('X', 2), ('Z', 1), ('W', 2)]]

The second line inserts the level at the start of each sublist (starting at 1 instead of zero).

The third line converts the lists to tuples to match your desired output.

```
from collections import Counter

result = [Counter(idx[i]).items() for i in range(len(idx))]

[result[i].insert(0, 'Level {0}'.format(i+1)) for i in range(len(idx))]

result = tuple(tuple(result[i]) for i in range(len(result)))

>>> result
(('Level 1', ('A', 3), ('C', 1), ('B', 2)),
 ('Level 2', ('Y', 1), ('X', 2), ('Z', 1), ('W', 2)))
```

Counter returns an unordered dictionary which is then converted into a list.  Depending on your needs, you may want to sort it.

If so, insert this between steps 1 and 2:

```
[result[i].sort() for i in range(len(result))]
```

Comment: Neat answer.  Although I just noticed that he seems to want ```X,1``` listed twice rather than as ```X,2``` (although the other answers do the exact same as yours)

Comment: Good spot.  I didn't notice that.  The difficulty then is how the indices align.  Here they contain the same number of elements in each, but it is possible that they don't in which case it isn't clear how they should be aligned.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way:

```
ind = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C'],
          ['W', 'W', 'X', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']])
df = pd.DataFrame(index=ind).reset_index()
df.apply(pd.Series.value_counts).fillna(0)
```

which produces:

```
   level_0  level_1
A        3        0
B        2        0
C        1        0
W        0        2
X        0        2
Y        0        1
Z        0        1
```